# Объединение второго элемента словарей в списке с одинаковым первым ключом

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Есть список  со списками со словарями:

```
self.bids = [[{'price': 5, 'quantity': 6}, 1, 0], [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 2, 0], [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 3, 0], [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 4, 0], [{'price': 5, 'quantity': 6}, 5, 0]]
```

нужно привести это к такому виду:

```
new_list =  [{'price': 5, 'quantity': 12}, {'price': 6, 'quantity': 15}]
```

То есть, в случае если в общей куче словарей значения "price" совпадают, то нужно объединить их в единый словарь внутри нового списка, при этом сложив значение "quantity".
Код который я написал - работает не правильно, по какой то причине он перезаписывает родительский словарь в цикле:

```
def snapshot(self):

    bids_list = list()
    bids_snapshot = dict()

    for bids_dict in self.bids:

        if bids_dict[0]['price'] == bids_snapshot.get('price'):
            bids_snapshot['quantity'] += bids_dict[0]['quantity']

        else:
            bids_snapshot['price'] = bids_dict[0]['price']
            bids_snapshot['quantity'] = bids_dict[0]['quantity']
            bids_list.append(copy(bids_snapshot))
    return bids_list
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

bids = [[{'price': 5, 'quantity': 6}, 1, 0], [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 2, 0], [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 3, 0], [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 4, 0], [{'price': 5, 'quantity': 6}, 5, 0]]

res=pd.DataFrame([x[0] for x in bids]).groupby("price").sum().reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

res :

```
[{'price': 5, 'quantity': 12}, {'price': 6, 'quantity': 15}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Реализация на "чистом" python

```
def snapshot(bids):
    temp = {}
    for item in bids:
        dct = item[0]
        price = dct['price']
        if price not in temp:
            temp[price] = dct.copy()
        else:
            temp[price]['quantity'] += dct['quantity']
    return list(temp.values())


bids = [[{'price': 5, 'quantity': 6}, 1, 0],
        [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 2, 0],
        [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 3, 0],
        [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 4, 0],
        [{'price': 5, 'quantity': 6}, 5, 0]]

print(snapshot(bids))  # [{'price': 5, 'quantity': 12}, {'price': 6, 'quantity': 15}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Чистый питон, но с использованием `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = [[{'price': 5, 'quantity': 6}, 1, 0], [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 2, 0], [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 3, 0], [{'price': 6, 'quantity': 5}, 4, 0], [{'price': 5, 'quantity': 6}, 5, 0]]

dd = defaultdict(int)
k1, k2 = 'price', 'quantity'
for i in d:
    dd[i[0][k1]] += i[0][k2]

new_list = [{k1: k, k2: dd[k]} for k in dd]
print(new_list)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'price': 5, 'quantity': 12}, {'price': 6, 'quantity': 15}]
```